# Cilantro wilting

Tags: cilantro

[image]

Hello, I recently bought some cilantro. Today I noticed they were wilting, I was wondering why this is happening and advice.

Comment: Did you buy it in a supermarket, or from outdoors at a nursery or garden centre? Have you put it straight outdoors? What part of the world are you in?